# What's the equivalent of the PHPMailer's AddStringAttachment when using Mailgun via PHP and CURL?

Tags: php, curl

[This is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781940/sending-a-string-attachment-using-mailgun) to the question when using Mailgun's class. I'm seeking to find an answer that applies to using CURL inside of PHP.

---

Using PHPMailer's class, I can send multiple attachments in the following manner:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($attachment1, $title1);
$mail->AddStringAttachment($attachment2, $title2);
```

Because I am not fetching a file from the server, and am instead composing in a string, I need to specify the title for each enclosure.

---

Now, I'd like to accomplish that using Mailgun via PHP and CURL. So far, I am utilizing the following technique for sending mail without attachments:

```
$api_key="[my api key]";
$domain ="[my domain]";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:'.$api_key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/'.$domain.'/messages');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    "from" => "[sender]",
    "to" => $to,
    "subject" => $subject,
    "html" => $content
));
```

Following this same convention of specifying the fields in an array, what's the equivalent of sending string attachments and specifying the titles using PHP and CURL with Mailgun?

Comment: Why not using Mailgun PHP api ?

Comment: I might have to, but since I'm only using a sliver of MG's capabilities, I wouldn't mind having one less library to maintain.

Comment: If you want to add only one attachment, its easy, just add `'attachment' => '@/path/to/file.ext',` to your `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` array.  But their API states that all the attachments use the form name `'attachment'` so you won't be able to add more than one to the array without overwriting the previous.  In their API library, the construct the multipart/form-data request using code from GuzzleHttp so it isn't a problem adding more than one.

Comment: @drew010: Thank you for your reply. I discovered that the "attachment" parameter can be numbered (e.g., "attachment[1]"). Unfortunately, I could not find a way around creating temporary files (in order to produce the desired attachment name), but at least it's now working (as shown in the function posted in answer to my own question). Your comment started me down the correct path. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave up on using string attachments and instead created two temporary files (based on content previously composed by another function) inside of a temporary directory (with the directory name based on the user's unique ID). (Thanks to drew010 for starting me down the correct path.)

I doubt the following function will be useful to others as is, but perhaps various portions will be helpful to others desiring similar functionality.

```
function sendFormattedEmail ($coverNote, $attachment1, $title1, $attachment2, $title2) {
    global $userID, $account;

    if (!file_exists("temp_{$userID}")) {
        mkdir("temp_{$userID}");
    }

    file_put_contents("temp_{$userID}/{$title1}", $attachment1);
    file_put_contents("temp_{$userID}/{$title2}", $attachment2);

    $api_key="[api_key]";
    $domain ="[my_domain]";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:'.$api_key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/'.$domain.'/messages');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        "from" => "[my_return_address]",
        "to" => $account,
        "subject" => "your requested files",
        "text" => $coverNote,
        "attachment[1]" => new CurlFile("temp_{$userID}/{$title1}"),
        "attachment[2]" => new CurlFile("temp_{$userID}/{$title2})"
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = strtolower(str_replace("\n", "", trim($response)));
    $result=  json_decode($response, true);
    $status = explode(".", $result["message"]);

    if ($status[0] == "queued") {
        echo json_encode(array ("result" => "success"));
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array ("result" => "failure"));
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    unlink ("temp_{$userID}/{$title1}");
    unlink ("temp_{$userID}/{$title2}");
    rmdir ("temp_{$userID}");
}
```

As shown above, the function strips the newline characters from Mailgun's response in order to enable the use of json_encode. The trim and lowercase conversion are just my preference.

After reporting the result back to the calling function, it removes the two temporary files and then the temporary directory.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, was very helpful

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to know that it was useful.